# Is there a way to break long numbers ("$100000000") into more readable triads ("$100 000 000") with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page with lots of big number values. Millions and billions of dollars going everywhere. And it is hard to read these numbers, so my client asks me to break them into more readable chunks of three symbols, "$100000000" => "$100 000 000".

This is completely reasonable request, but the problem is that I do not want to do this on server-side, and I do not want to do this with javascript. You see, I have a really big heap of javascript already running on this page, doing complex computations on these long numbers, and it will be really difficult to insert a `parseReadableStringToInteger()` in every place that reads data from page and a `writeIntegerAsReadableString()` in every place that writes results back to page.

So, I am thinking of using CSS to make long string display as a set of short chunks. My first thought was of `-moz-column` and `-webkit-column`, but unfortunately, they work only with words that are already separated by space.

Maybe there is another way? Any suggestions are welcome.

p.s. Cross-browser compatibility is not required. I'm ok with Gecko and/or Webkit.

Comment: Not as far as I know with CSS(3), plus not all browsers would be able to view the numbers in the way you'd want if it was done with CSS3. Why not just do it server-side? Seems like by far the easiest answer to your problem.

Comment: I don't think there are any ways to do this - server side output would indeed be best.

Comment: My hopes for some CSS3 magic are really high, because my knowledge of its powers is shallow. Some bizarre combination on word-wrap: break-word; and -moz-column and magic: more-magic;, anyone?

Comment: Would it be a problem if it only worked in Firefox 3? If so, I think you need to stop looking for a CSS solution.

Comment: Of course I'll throw in the ol' i8n objection that not all cultures group digits into groups of 3

Comment: @Peter M: Thank you for your useful comment. Why should I bother about other cultures? Some cultures don't even use arabic digits, should I think about them, too?

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question. However I don't think it is possible right now.

Comment: @egarcia: I almost did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341126/is-there-a-way-to-break-long-numbers-100000000-into-more-readable-triads/2341458#2341458

Comment: You also don't want to do it server-side, because presentation is the job of CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to find a JavaScript way to do this, I'm pretty certain. Any CSS technique, even if it were possible, wouldn't be cross-browser.

Comment: Cross-browser compatibility is not an issue for the moment. I'm ok with Gecko and/or Webkit.

Answer (score 15):

There is no way to do it via CSS, but you can extend Number type like this:

```
    Number.prototype.formatMoney = function(c, d, t){
    var n = this, c = isNaN(c = Math.abs(c)) ? 2 : c, d = d == undefined ? "," : d, t = t == undefined ? "." : t, s = n < 0 ? "-" : "", i = parseInt(n = Math.abs(+n || 0).toFixed(c)) + "", j = (j = i.length) > 3 ? j % 3 : 0;
       return s + (j ? i.substr(0, j) + t : "") + i.substr(j).replace(/(\d{3})(?=\d)/g, "$1" + t) + (c ? d + Math.abs(n - i).toFixed(c).slice(2) : "");
    };
```

then use it like this:

```
var count = 10000000;
count.formatMoney(2, '.', ' ')
```

Answer (score 6):

Damn it, I'm almost there!!

```
span {
    display: block;
    -moz-column-gap:5px;
    -moz-column-width:24px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

<span>100000</span>
<span>1000000</span>
<span>10000000</span>
<span>100000000</span>
```

gives me

```
100 000
100 000 0
100 000 00
100 000 000
```

The only thing that is left is somehow start the splitting from the right. Now experimenting with `direction: rtl` and such :)

Comment: You'll need to be absolutely sure of the pixel width of your typeface, surely? Try using numbers that don't end with all zeroes (so the column gaps would be at varying pixel offsets from the right of the strings).

Comment: Well, yeah, sure, it will need some fine tuning on a later stage :)

Comment: Can you use some transformation to turn the text to right-to-left and then back to left-to-right (i.e., through nesting)

Comment: Just thought I'd mention that it might be worth looking at CSS3 pseudo-selector `nth-child(n)`. Problem is, it won't select "nth-letters", but it would work if you wrapped all your digits in spans. (ugly, though) Then you could do: `p :nth-child(3n){margin-left:3px}` which is in the same area as the column-properties you're messing around with.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't willing to use JavaScript to change the formatting, you should change their format from the server...ie, before rendering the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion that would work, **although even I will admit it isn't very nice**...

Using the jQuery framework, $("#myElement").text() returns just the text (not any nested html). So you could do this:

```
<p>$<span id="myElement"><span class="triad">1</span><span class="triad">000</span><span class="triad">000</span></p>
```

And apply some padding or margin to make it more readable.

When you then call:

```
$("#myElement").text();
```

You would get the plain 1000000 back.

CSS:

```
.triad { padding-left: 5px; }
```

Comment: I already mentioned this approach in the question text, note the "parseReadableStringToInteger()" and "writeIntegerAsReadableString()" functions. I will go this way if there is no another way, because there is, like, 230kb of javascript to patch, and I am lazy. :)

Comment: You should still be able to use `document.getElementById("myElement").textContent` to get the text back. `innerHTML` is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

n1313, http://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/content-formatting ;) it's not a solution, just idea

Answer (score 1):

```
function largeNumberToReadableNumber(number){
  var str = Math.floor(amount)+""; //make the integer a string
  var sub = str.substring(str.length-3, str.length); //the last three characters
  newstr = " "+sub;
  var i = 1;
  while (sub.length >= 3){
    sub = str.substring(str.length-((i+1)*3),str.length-(i*3)); //next three characters
    newstr = sub + " " + newstr; //append the characters
    i+=1;
  }
  return newstr;
}

largeNumberToReadable(120312381124124); //will output " 120 312 381 124  124"
```

I am sure this can be written better and shorter but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I found this piece of javascript which might help you out if you are going to do it client-side:
http://homepage.mac.com/ruske/ruske/C2127905073/E844527267/Media/FormatInteger.js

Answer (score 0):

No CSS manipulates strings. Sry you'll have to do it with JS

Answer (score 0):

I wish this was possible with CSS :( you can not ***get*** text value and use that in later operations using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

How about having the number twice: Once for displaying and once for manipulation like this:

```
<span class="money" data-value="1000000">$ 1 000 000</span>
```

Then you can easly use `getAttribute('data-value')` to get to the value from your JS and format the number any way you want.

[`data-*` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) are a new feature in HTML 5, but pretty much all current browsers already support it (modulu the `.dataset` property in the DOM, so you'll have to use `getAttribute()` in current/older browsers).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is using `:after` and `:before` with `content:" "`
Then you just need something that dynamically add a tag around the right numbers and style it.